# Can't login via FTP with cUrl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm implementing a function that should upload a file. I'm using cUrl and Qt/C++.

```
int FtpController::uploadFile()
{
#define UPLOAD_FILE_AS "temp.txt"
#define RENAME_FILE_TO "renamed-and-fine.txt"

    CURL* curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode result;
    FILE* hd_src;
    const auto str = getFileName().toStdString(); // getFileName() provides the full path
    const auto* const localFile = str.c_str();
    struct stat file_info;
    unsigned long fsize;

    struct curl_slist* headerlist = nullptr;
    static const char buf_1[] = "RNFR " UPLOAD_FILE_AS;
    static const char buf_2[] = "RNTO " RENAME_FILE_TO;

    /* get the file size of the local file */
    if (stat(localFile, &file_info)) {
        printf("Couldn't open '%s': %s\n", localFile, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    fsize = (unsigned long)file_info.st_size;

    printf("Local file size: %lu bytes.\n", fsize);

    /* get a FILE * of the same file */
    hd_src = fopen(localFile, "rb");

    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        /* build a list of commands to pass to libcurl */
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf_1);
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf_2);
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, _params.port);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, _params.username.toStdString().c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, _settingsController->getSystemSettings()->getPass().toStdString().c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, _params.timeout);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, _params.url.toString().toStdString().c_str());
            /* If you intend to use this on windows with a libcurl DLL, you must use CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION as well */
        }
        /* Now run off and do what you have been told! */
        result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (result != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(result));

        /* clean up the FTP commands list */
        curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

It returns: `curl_easy_perform() failed: Access denied to remote resource`
However, my web-hosting returns:
[image]

What's wrong? I triple checked all input.

The file is definitely found, the curl writes in the terminal `Local file size: 575131 bytes.`, though I don't ask it.

If I change the pass, it returns `curl_easy_perform() failed: Login denied` and if the URL is different or I try **uploading anything** it says `curl_easy_perform() failed: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

This is the third approach to sending files via FTP, I need a help.

Comment: Did you try it like the example does? https://curl.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html Your code is similar, but is missing critical parts, like the read function callback.

Comment: I copied my code from that and I removed the callback simply for StackOverflow as redundant.

Comment: You say redundant, I say there's a really good reason your code doesn't upload anything since it never reads from the file. There's a fair amount of what looks like important code missing from your example as well, like allowing uploads, setting the remote, running the commands you added to the headerlist, and the file size.

Comment: My luck has just solved it. I've read all over the internet for solutions and none was helpful, but one, trivial. I'll post the investigation result tomorrow as I don't know what the real reason was (maybe I had to set an agent?) I'm utterly tired to get that today, 10 hours in a row...